# how to highlight the the text of a jtable cell?

Tags: java, search, jtable, highlight

jdialog which load the user log:
[image: jdialog which load the user log]

This image is after the user search row from a table:
[image: This image is after the user search row from a table]

This image supposedly I want to achieve:
[image: This image supposedly I want to achieve]  I just want to put a highlight the text of a jtable cell whenever the user search a row

```
The method below is to load the user log  to a table

void loadUserLog(){
        try {
            dialog.connect();
            query = "SELECT user_log.login_date, user_log.login_time, user_log.logout_time "
                + "FROM user_log WHERE user_log.username_id = '"+ username +"'";
            pst = dialog.con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] userLogData = {rs.getString("login_date"), rs.getString("login_time"), rs.getString("logout_time")};
                tblUserLogModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblUserLog.getModel();
                tblUserLogModel.addRow(userLogData);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }
    }
```

```
     **The code below is the key release event of textfield**

try {
    dialog.connect();
    // this query will search a row from database that enter the user
    query = "SELECT user_log.login_date, user_log.login_time, user_log.logout_time "
        + "FROM user_log WHERE (user_log.login_date LIKE '"+txtSearch.getText()+"%' OR "
        + "user_log.login_time LIKE '"+txtSearch.getText()+"%' OR user_log.logout_time"
        + " LIKE '"+txtSearch.getText()+"%') AND user_log.username_id = '"+username+"'";
    
    pst = dialog.con.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    
    if (txtSearch.getText().equals("")) {
        tblUserLogModel.setRowCount(0);
        loadUserLog();
    }  
    else{
        tblUserLogModel.setRowCount(0);
        while(rs.next()) {
            Object\[\] userLogData = {rs.getString("login_date"), rs.getString("login_time"),                    rs.getString("logout_time")};
            tblUserLogModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblUserLog.getModel();
            tblUserLogModel.addRow(userLogData);
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
}
```

How can I do that using the code above?

When using that code, it will just load the row to jtable if that row has an equal string from the beginning base from the inputted text by the user

Comment: by extending the cell renderer for the related columns - see the relevant part of the official tutorial [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: I realize this is probably just for a school or learning assignment, but… you would be wise to avoid code like `WHERE user_log.username_id = '"+ username +"'"`, which is **very dangerous** and one of the leading causes of sites being hacked.  Ironically, you are already using `prepareStatement`, which is good.  Your query should be `WHERE user_log.username_id = ?` and you should add `pst.setString(1, username);` before executing the query.  This guarantees that even if the username contains SQL statements, they will never be executed.  (Search the web for “SQL injection” to learn more.)